How to fix an error with fabric loom while modding Minecraft?
This is my first time making a minecraft mod for fabric 1.21.3. I used a fabric mod template from the
official fabric website, and put it into Intellij IDEA and I waited for gradle to build at the start, but then it came out with:
 Build file 'C:\Users\...\unrelated-1.21.3\build.gradle' line: 2

Plugin [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '1.8-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Note: unrelated is the name of my mod
What I hoped would happen is my project would build and I could begin programming. Here is the part of my build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "fabric-loom" version "1.8-SNAPSHOT"
    id "maven-publish"
}

In my settings.gradle, I have:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "Fabric"
            url = "https://maven.fabricmc.net/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}`


When I ran the issue with stacktrace, it came out with:
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '1.8-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin. For more available plugins, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/plugin_reference.html in the Gradle documentation.)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'fabric-loom:fabric-loom.gradle.plugin:1.8-SNAPSHOT')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Fabric(https://maven.fabricmc.net/)
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository


You can see that it searched in the mave.fabricmc.net, which I then accessed on my browser and confirmed the version of fabric-loom was correct. I have tried using a different software (visual studio code) and also have tried using a different version of fabric loom, I have watched other videos in which they were able to build immediately without error. I also tried the template on github rather than the generator, all to no avail. Please help me.
